# Angular 1.6 $http.get unable to read from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I am trying to read the json data from a static json file that I have for testing on a local web server but I cannot get anything to show up with using the $http.get() service. I looked at a few other similar questions here but all accepted answers account for use of the promise methods, however on the angularjs **v1.6.x**+ these have been depreciated.

Initially I tried setting my json data on a variable inside of the controller, and everything worked fine, however once I moved to a JSON file nothing shows up. My first error was that I was unaware the JSON file has **to be in ANSI format** for the JSON.parse() angular calls to be able to work. Before switching the file encoding to ANSI I was getting syntax errors and my json structure was correct. (some text editor like Dreamweaver will create JSON files in UTF-8 format).

At this point when I inspect the webpage there are no JS errors on the console whatsoever, however no data shows up at all. Here is what I have:
My events.json

```
     [
          {
            "day" : "Monday",
            "objective" : "Pipeline",
            "sessions" : [
            {
                "title" : "Leadership Excellence Luncheon",
                "start" : "11:30am",
                "end" : "1:00pm",
                "location": "room A"
            },
            {
                "title" : "Veteran Resume Workshop",
                "start" : "1:15pm",
                "end" : "2:00pm",
                "location": "room B",
                "speakers" : [
                {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "title": "Analyst",
                    "company": "Appel",
                    "headshot" : "http://placehold.it/119x134.jpg",
                    "bio": "john-doe/",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jane Doe",
                    "title" : "VP",
                    "company": "Lancer",
                    "headshot" : "http://placehold.it/119x134.jpg",
                }
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
     {
        "day" : "Tuesday",
         "objective" : "Pipeline",
         "sessions" : [
           {
            "title" : "Leadership Excellence Luncheon",
            "start" : "11:30am",
            "end" : "1:00pm",
            "location": "room A"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Veteran Resume Workshop",
            "start" : "1:15pm",
            "end" : "2:00pm",
            "location": "room B",
            "speakers" : [
                {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "title": "Analyst",
                    "company": "Appel",
                    "headshot" : "http://placehold.it/119x134.jpg",
                    "bio": "john-doe/",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jane Doe",
                    "title" : "VP",
                    "company": "Lancer",
                    "headshot" : "http://placehold.it/119x134.jpg",
                }
            ]
           }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Here is my app.js

```
(function() {
     var app = angular.module('Agendas',[]);


     app.controller('TableController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope,$http) {
      $scope.title = "test";
      $scope.events = [];



     $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/ang/data/events.json',       
    }).then( function(response) {
        $scope.events = response;
       });

    }]);

 })();
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
.....
</head>
<body>
....
<div id="agenda" class="mainCont container-fluid well" ng-app="Agendas" ng-controller="TableController">
 <div id="day" ng-repeat="event in events">
 <h1>{{ event.day }} &mdash; {{ event.objective }}</h1>
 <div id="sess" ng-repeat="session in event.sessions">
 <div style="width: 140px; float: left; clear: left;">{{ session.start }} - {{ session.end }}<br><br><em>Location: {{ session.location }}</em></div> <div style="float: left;"><em>{{ session.title }}</em>     <br>
    <div class="panelist" ng-repeat="speaker in session.speakers"><img ng-src="{{ speaker.headshot }}"><br>
    <a ng-href="{{ speaker.bio }}">{{ speaker.name }}</a><br>
    {{ speaker.title }} <br>
    {{ speaker.company }}</div>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="aghr"></div>
 </div>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your JSON file contains some errors. It could be related.

1. The ending tag should be one to close the array. `]`instead of `}`.
2. The last field of a JSON object should not have a comma. E.g.:

`{
   "name": "John Doe",
   "title": "Analyst",
   "company": "Appel",
   "headshot" : "http://placehold.it/119x134.jpg",
   "bio": "john-doe/", <--- remove comma
}`

You can use a website as [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON.

** As suggested, you might have to clear the browser cache first.

** Additionally  change

```
$scope.events = response;
```

to

```
$scope.events = response.data;
```

Comment: Oh that's a neat website! Thanks! Seems that was indeed the problem. By the way the first time I tried refreshing my app page after updating the data nothing changed. Had to clear the cache first. Might want to suggest that on your answer as well in case someone in the future has similar problems. **EDIT: Additionally forgot I also changed response to response.data**